# pyinstaller package cx_Oracle issue (on CentOS)

Tags: python, linux, centos, pyinstaller, cx-oracle

I wrote a very simple python script (db.py):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cx_Oracle

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn("192.168.100.15", "1521", "zhy")
print dsn_tns
conn = cx_Oracle.connect("winvoice", "winvoice", dsn_tns)
cursor = conn.cursor()
print cursor
```

It runs ok in console:

```
[ddgg@office11 1]$ ./db.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:1256: UserWarning: /home/ddgg/.python-eggs is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.100.15)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=zhy)))
<cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to winvoice@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.100.15)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=zhy)))>>
[ddgg@office11 1]$
```

Then I packaged it using pyinstaller, simply with: `pyinstaller db.py`,
then a `db.spec` generated:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['db.py'],
             pathex=['/workcopy/sae/rtgame/1'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None,
             excludes=None,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='db',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='db')
```

It goes well with no error, but when I run it, I got:

```
[ddgg@office11 1]$ dist/db/db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
[ddgg@office11 1]$
```

What's going wrong?
In the python console, cx_Oracle can be imported correctly:

```
[ddgg@office11 1]$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep 10 2015, 14:06:03) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:1256: UserWarning: /home/ddgg/.python-eggs is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: What do you get when executing `import cx_Oracle; print cx_Oracle.__file__` on a _Python_ interactive shell?

Comment: @Yoel Thanks for your attention. `>>> print cx_Oracle.__file__`I got:
`/home/ddgg/.python-eggs/cx_Oracle-5.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg-tmp/cx_Oracle.so`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a file called `hook-cx_Oracle.py` with the following content:

```py
import os
import glob
import itertools

try:
    # PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES is unavailable in older versions
    from PyInstaller.hooks.hookutils import PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
except ImportError:
    try:
        from importlib.machinery import EXTENSION_SUFFIXES as PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
    except ImportError:
        import imp
        PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES = set([f[0] for f in imp.get_suffixes()
                                     if f[2] == imp.C_EXTENSION])

def hook(mod):
    module_directory = os.path.dirname(mod.__file__)
    bundled = []

    for libname, ext in itertools.product((mod.__name__, ),
                                          PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES):
        bundled.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(module_directory, libname + ext)))

    for f in bundled:
        name = os.path.join(mod.__name__, os.path.basename(f))
        if hasattr(mod, 'pyinstaller_binaries'):
            mod.pyinstaller_binaries.append((name, f, 'BINARY'))
        else: # mod.pyinstaller_binaries is unavailable in older versions
            mod.binaries.append((name, f, 'BINARY'))

    return mod
```

When building, supply the path to the directory in which you placed the file as a value to the `--additional-hooks-dir` argument, as follows:

```
--additional-hooks-dir=<path_to_directory_of_hook_file>
```